# Google OAuth Redirect Uri in Apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, asp.net-core, google-oauth

I'm trying to setup a web server using Apache as reverse proxy connected to a ASP.NET CORE web application hosted by kestrel. I've followed the tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.1

The website uses the Google Calendar Api to get a users calanedar information. This works fine when I host it with Kestrel through Visual Studio. However, when I try to authenticate and select a Google Account through the web server, I get redirected to

**127.0.0.1:5000/signin-oidc**

which is not the desired result. (127.0.0.1:5000 is configured as the ProxyPass and ProxyReverse for Apache).

Since the web application works when I run without the Apache reverse proxy, I suspect there is some issues with the apache configuration. However, it might as well be a problem with the [Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/tree/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3) library I am using. I've used the [the integrationtests](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/tree/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3.IntegrationTests) as a guide on how to setup *startup.cs* and how to make the Api requests.

Edit:

So I asked the developers of the library that I’m using. The redirect uri is bound to the endpoint that kestrel I listening on. The question is here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1680

So it can only work if I can somehow get kestrel to know the “actual” domain name or public IP of my server... From my research, this seems near if not impossible. I will be looking into other implementation options for authorization and authentication.

Comment: Are you using the OAuth2 authorization code flow with Google? If so, what are you using as the `redirect_uri` query parameter? It's possible that your webserver is using some internal host value instead of your public one.

Comment: @TreyGriffith The library that I'm using controls the entire challange (there is no need for an account controller to emit the challange). So I would assume that it is responsible for the flow aswell. It seems that the localhost:5000/signin-oidc is the default rediret_uri. I can change it to localhost:5000/Controller/Action with the CallbackPath. 

However, from further reasearch, it would seem that Google Sign-In is more favorable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution was found!

In my endless seach and noobiness I've found out that I've deleted the forward header for my VirtualHost for apache. I've also added the ProxyPreserveHost option.

I changed the virtual host to include

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

Comment: RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https          ProxyPreserveHost On   ---Adding above two Directives does the job

Answer (score 1):

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

Adding above two Directives does the job

References:

[ProxyPreserveHost On](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39271_01/studio.300/studio_install/src/cidi_studio_reverse_proxy_apache_proxypreservehost.html)

[RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using net core, adding the right configuration to virtual host is not enough, you need to add

```
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
        
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Forwarded-Proto", out var protoHeaderValue) &&
                protoHeaderValue == "https")
            {
                context.Request.Scheme = "https";
            }
            return next();
        });
```

and

```
.AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                    OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri.Replace("http://", "https://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                };
```